# declaring input stream

Tags: c++

I have a C++ code with

```
ifstream myfile;
myfile.open("input");
```

and then has commands like:

```
myfile.getline(inp,256);
```

Question: How can I modify `myfile.open("input")` so that `myfile` is associated with `cin` instead of `"input"`?

I don't want to change all `myfile.getline` commands to `cin.getline`.

Declaring `myfile=cin` does not compile.

Answer (score 3):

Use an `istream&` reference instead:

```
std::istream& myfile(std::cin);
```

Answer (score 2):

Separate it out into a function and take the `std::istream&` as an argument. Then you can execute on both `std::cin` and `myfile` as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

You can put your code into a function that takes a reference to a std::istream, e.g.

```
void process_data( std::istream & istr )
{ ... }
```

Then you can call this function both with any std::ifstream and with std::cin:

```
std::ifstream myfile;
...
process_data( myfile );
process_data( std::cin );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you insist in using an `std::ifstream` you can replace the `std::streambuf` of the base `std::istream` (`std::ifstream` overloads `rdbuf()` so you can't use it directly):

```
std::ifstream file;
if (use_cin) {
    file.std::istream::rdbuf(std::cin.rdbuf());
}
```